# expo build:android is not starting

Tags: android, build, expo, release

After created Google play release, expo build:android getting below error,
ERROR: After run ‘expo build:android’, metro bundle doesnt start and expo prints below output. PS: ‘expo start’ and ‘expo build:ios’ working fine
Choose the build type you would like: › apk

Checking if there is a build in progress…

Accessing credentials for in project

Publishing to channel ‘default’…

{}

Expo CLI 3.24.2 environment info:
System:
OS: macOS 10.15.6
Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 12.16.2 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
IDEs:
Android Studio: 3.6 AI-192.7142.36.36.6392135
Xcode: 11.4.1/11E503a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
expo: ^38.0.0 => 38.0.9
react: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0
react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz => 0.62.2
react-navigation: ^3.3.0 => 3.13.0

Comment: I have somewhat the same problem. I'm stuck at "Accessing credentials for in project"

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the problem. The issue was localisation for ios location and camera access. 'en' language was the issue and when I deleted it, problem solved.